# Postgresq 9.5l: peer authenticate user with usermap (provided user name (^dbuser^) and authenticated user name (^sysuser^) do not match)

Tags: authentication, postgresql, debian-jessie

On my server I am trying to peer authenticate some users using usermap on the postgresql 9.5 installation. What I am trying to do is to map user mailreader as you can see:

```
postgres=# \du
                              List of roles
 Role name  |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 mailreader |                                                | {}
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Into system's user root,dovecot,postfix. Therefore I edited my `pg_ident.cong` and put the following content:

```
mailmap         dovecot                 mailreader
mailmap         postfix                 mailreader
mailmap         root                    mailreader
```

Also I edited the `pg_hba.conf` and appended with the following content:

```
local    mail        all                     peer map=mailmap
```

When I try to connect via `sudo psql -U mailreader -d mail` command I get:

> psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "mailreader"

error.

I also tried the following configuration:

```
local    mail            all                                     ident map=mailmap
```

Without any progress.

May I have some help?

## Edit 1

The generated logs regarding the error are:

```
2017-06-27 19:10:10 UTC [1188-1] mailreader@mail LOG:  provided user name (mailreader) and authenticated user name (root) do not match
2017-06-27 19:10:10 UTC [1188-2] mailreader@mail FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "mailreader"
2017-06-27 19:10:10 UTC [1188-3] mailreader@mail DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 90: "local   all             all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to comment the line:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Or to put it below the following line:

```
local    mail            all                             ident map=mailmap
```

On `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

`local    mail        app                     peer map=mailmap` looks wrong, you want either `all` or `mailreader` instead off `app`. Otherwise, your configuration looks correct. You might also need to reload postgres after changing `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: It was all in the end and I posted wrong.